# "panelized" procedural material

Tags: mesh, uv, procedural, panel

i'm working with a rust procedural material from another tutorial. I need each panel of my mesh to display an instance of the material, rather than having it connect across edges. That is to say, how it would look "as-built" with individual metal panels. How do I specify that in my shader node network?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked:

Mark all edges as seams then select all and UV unwrap.

Comment: Lightmap Pack under UV also does a good job of jumbling things up.  If you don't care about following topology the possibilities are endless.

Comment: That was my next question - so I would now like to randomly displace the tiling across each of three mirrors of the original object. Now if you look at the orthos, the material appears like butterfly wings across the projection and I'd like it to be randomized. What will accomplish that?

Comment: it would be better to post a new question with pictures and specifics

Comment: @CharlieT Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on how? Perhaps add describe the steps or indicate the keyboard shortcuts, and add screenshot showing the results

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using assigned colors for each face as input for a Mapping node that affects whatever texture coordinate you are using.